# Where should I write business logic when using Codeigniter framework: controller or model?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

If you use Codeigniter framework, you have two folders already built named `controllers` and `models`. When developing a web application where I should write my business logic, in `controllers` or `models`?

I also want to know if I keep business logic in `models`. Should I segregate business logic and database query part or put both in same class?

Comment: Always in the controller, this is a core principle of MVC

Comment: @GeekJosh that is only if you are using MVC which is a presentation layer, not an architectural one.

Comment: @GeekJosh what you told conflict with following http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/165444/where-to-put-business-logic-in-mvc-design http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/165444/where-to-put-business-logic-in-mvc-design

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's better to keep the business logic out of the models and controllers, to put it into *services*, which are nothing but class to service your business logic. For example if you have a notification system, you may have a `NotifierInterface` and then a `EmailNotifier`, `SmsNotifier`, etc. The model is then just a POPO (Plain Old PHP Objects), that encapsulate only the data with no extra logic in it. And the controllers are the small glue between your HTTP layer (Request/Response) and your logic/models.

You could create a `services` folder and put them there.

That said, you can organise it as you wish really. Some frameworks like CI are giving you a basic file structure but nobody forces you to do it. To take the example of the Notifier, in my app here's what I have:

```
src/
    Notifier/
        Email/
            MandrillNotifier
            MailgunNotifier
        Sms/
            TwillioNotifier
```

And for example your `controllers`   in my app are under `src/Http/Controller`.

Comment: ..so where to put that service layer, because when you use codeigniter, you have 'models' and 'controllers' folders already made, and only controllers can access model classes